# Add a "-" when the option is disabled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have options disabled and enabled for some options in rails admin panel. I am updating the panel titles on the select and disselect of checkboxes and radio buttons.

so when the option is disabled for a particular checkbox, I want to display a "-" instead of its value.

say for checkbox image "suraj", I have disabled "gon250" so when I click on "suraj", the title for "gon250" should become " - "

```
    // Disable related options
disables = JSON.parse(elem.attr("data-option-disables"));
alert(disables);
for(i = 0; i < disables.length; i++) {
  elem_to_be_disabled = $("input[data-option-subid='option_subid_" + disables[i] + "']");
  elem_to_be_disabled.prop("disabled", true).addClass("c_disabled");
  elem_to_be_disabled.closest(".part_option_wrapper").prepend("<div class='option_overlay'/>");
}
$("#selected_part_" + elem.attr("data-option-part")).find(".selected_part_option").html(elem.attr("data-option-name"));

// Enable related options
enables = JSON.parse(elem.attr("data-option-enables"));
for(i = 0; i < enables.length; i++) {
  elem_to_be_enabled = $("[data-option-subid='option_subid_" + enables[i] + "']");
  console.log(elem_to_be_enabled);
  elem_to_be_enabled.prop("selected", true);
  elem_to_be_enabled.prop("checked", true);
}
});
```

Please Help.

Thanks